# How to hide CPT single pages from Google while allowing to view them in admin?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

Adding `public => false` in `register_post_type()`'s arguments would solve the Google problem but then I have no access to the CPT posts in admin. A redirect [like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/128637/11634) prevents from viewing the pages but they still show up in Google.

Is what I want even possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) - it says the following:

> public (boolean) (optional) Controls how the type is visible to
>   authors (show_in_nav_menus, show_ui) and readers (exclude_from_search,
>   publicly_queryable).
>
> Default: false
>
> - 'true' - Implies exclude_from_search: false, publicly_queryable:    true, show_in_nav_menus: true, and show_ui:true. The built-in types
>     attachment, page, and post are similar to this.
> - 'false' - Implies exclude_from_search: true, publicly_queryable:    false, show_in_nav_menus: false, and show_ui: false. The built-in
>     types nav_menu_item and revision are similar to this. Best used if
>     you'll provide your own editing and viewing interfaces (or none at
>     all).

As you can see `public` is some kind of meta property. Set `public` to `false` but set `show_ui` to `true`. This should work.